# silverlight treeview

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, data-binding, treeview

Using WCF i get data from server. Data contains Folders and these folders contain queries. I need to set folder icon(expanded collapsed) on the folder node and another icon on query.
TreeView is bound to this collection using HierarchicalDataTemplate. I tryed to do it with converter but failed. I also want it to be MVVM compliant.

```
<sdk:TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}" >
        <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Queries}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IconConverter}}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"   />
                </StackPanel>
            </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </sdk:TreeView>
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the 'ContentPresenter' with the 'image' control,and bind the path of the your icon file to the 'source' property of your 'image' control.